# Como puedo instalar un repositorio de GitHub en Python?

Tags: python, github, instalacion, cluster

He estado trabajando con algoritmos basados en densidad últimamente, y para determinar la validez, o al menos tener una referencia, de la calidad del clustering, he usado el **coeficiente de silueta**

El caso es que este coeficiente funciona bien para grupos de forma más o menos redonda, por lo que para grupos con otras geometrías puede fallar.

Es por ello que investigando, he decidido implementar **DBCV**. Su implementación en Python está en GitHub, pero no se cómo instalarla para usarla! Soy novato, y aún no me manejo del todo bien... y en Internet me está costando encontrar como hacerlo específicamente.

Respositorio: https://github.com/christopherjenness/DBCV

Os dejo esto aquí por si os sirve. Hay un ejemplo en el "ReadMe" de como funciona.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar pip y la url git del proyecto

```
pip install git+https://github.com/christopherjenness/DBCV.git#egg=DBCV
```

pip tiene documentación sobre [su soporte para VCS](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support), si deseas leer más al respecto

No olvides incluir egg=<nombre-del-proyecto> para identificar el proyecto

La otra opción, menos automática, es descargar el proyecto como zip en el mismo github, descomprimirlo y ejecutar `setup.py`. No deberías solamente descargar los archivos que parecen "necesarios" debido a que pueden haber dependencias que no saltan a simple vista. En el caso del proyecto que muestras solo son `numpy` y `scipy`, pero hay otros paquetes más complejos que pueden darte errores por faltar algún otro paquete en algunos casos. Ejecutar `setup.py` o desde `pip` hace que se descarguen las dependencias automáticamente.

Comment: ¿No basta simplemente con copiar los .py del subdirectorio DBCV al directorio de mi/tu proyecto? Si puedes ampliar tu respuesta sería estupendo.

Comment: Me saltan los siguientes errores usando pip:                                       
 ERROR: Error [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/christopherjenness/DBCV.git 'C:\Users\peqes\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f7rkw4ek\dbcv_ff5dc42a25ec4f258051db422d228b21'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: Intenta instalar Git

Comment: Eso era lo que me fallaba, gracias!